# Deja Dup with Google Drive

Tags: deja-dup, duplicity

I have duplicity working with my Google Drive storage but I can't seem to configure Deja Dup to use that also. My duplicity command is

```
duplicity -v8 /home/[USERNAME]/Documents/ gdocs://[GOOGLE_USERNAME]@gmail.com/backup
```

I don't see an option in the Deja Dup interface but this seems like it should be in there. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Google Drive isn't supported by current versions of Deja Dup. It is in the works, but hasn't been released yet.

Comment: is there an alpha or beta I can try it out?